# Jenkins, configure choice parameter based on git branch

Tags: git, groovy, jenkins

I would like a jenkins job with 2 parameters. The first parameter is a populated with branches from a GIT repo.

Inside my GIT repo, there is a directory of files. I want to populate the second parameter based on the first one, from a specific branch.

Right now, I am using Git paramater with Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter.

This is my current script:

```
import groovy.io.FileType


command = "git checkout ${branch}"
command.execute()


def list = []

def dir = new File("./Integration Apps/")

dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file ->
  list << file
}

return list
```

Any idea how I can acomplish this?

Comment: What's the second parameter supposed to do?  I assume `branch` is the first? Can you change your example to show what you're trying to do, and how it's failing?

Comment: The second parameter is populated based on sub-folder names in this directory, /Integration Apps/

Comment: So what's wrong with `new File("./${parameterTwo}")`?  Also, you don't seem to wait for the git checkout to complete?

Comment: I can do that, but for some reason, it's not triggering the script when I change the parameter